# How do I use a v2 authentication header with Amazon PHP SDK v3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here's my code:

```
$client = new S3Client([
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'xxx',
    ],
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'US',
    'endpoint' => 'https://storage.googleapis.com',
    'signature_version' => 'v2',
]);
```

And I get this error:

> UnresolvedSignatureException in SignatureProvider.php line 61:
>
> Unable to resolve a signature for v2/s3/US. Valid signature versions include v4 and anonymous.

The documentation says that this is supported by adding a 'signature' => 'v2' but adding that parameter doesn't seem to do anything at all.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/configuration.html

This is using Laravel 5.1 with Amazon SDK v3.0.3

Comment: What if you remove "region"?  It doesn't serve a purpose here and the error message suggests it is contributing to the problem.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Region is a required parameter for S3Client.

Comment: Ugh.  Well, this pretty much sums up exactly why I've written my own AWS libraries from scratch and never use the SDKs. They do too much thinking for you, and it gets in the way. :/  Sorry I wasn't more helpful.

Comment: Does the Google endpoint you're trying to reach support v4 signing? S3 only supports v4 signing, and the SDK enforces that requirement.

Comment: I'm using Google Storage, so I guess not? They advertise that they support AWS but I guess no one over at Google actually uses the API in the way they advertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. v2 signatures are being phased out and are only supported on a [small number of services](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html) at this time, and S3 is not one of them. As the PHP SDK is built against AWS offerings, the authentication changes made to the services are reflected in the PHP client.